# import python class into another folder in a package

Tags: python, import, module, flask

I'm trying to import a python class from another folder of my python package but I this error "No module named models".

It's a Flask project.

```
-app
  |-run.py
  |-myapp
    |- libs
        |- updateto
            |- __init__.py      (empty)
            |- connection.py
        |- removeto
        |- __init__.py    (empty)
    |- static
    |- templates
    |- __init__.py      (NOT empty)
    |- routes.py
    |- models.py
```

My **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///maindb.db'

from models import db
db.init_app(app)

import myapp.routes
```

In my models.py I've a class named: application

And in connection.py I want import my class "application".
I've try with "from models import application" but I've this error "no modules named models".

I think it's possible to reach this goal with the modification of the init.py in the "updateto" folder but I'm no sure because I don't clearly understand the functioning of the **init**.py file...

Thanks

EDIT:

Which is weird, it's if under connection.py I add "import myapp" and "print(help(myapp))", I've this output:

```
Help on package myapp:

NAME
    myapp

FILE
    c:\app\myapp\__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    libs (package)
    models
    routes

DATA
    app = <Flask 'myapp'>
```

But if I try "from myapp import models" I've this error "ImportError: cannot import name models"

EDIT2:

If I try to add in connection.py "from myapp import app", it works but not if I try to import models... I'm very surprised. I've try to add in myapp/**init**.py:

```
__all__ = ["models", "routes]
```

But same error...

EDIT3:

hummmm I've move all my modules under the libs folder into myapp and when I try to put in connection.py "from model import application" I've always the same error "ImportError: cannot import name application"

Other test in connection.py:

```
import models
print(models)

Output:
<module 'myapp.models' from 'C:\app\myapp\models.pyc'>
```

I can import my module named models but I can't import the class under models.py

EDIT4:

Ok, I think I found the problem. It's my **ini**.py in myapp, because if I comment this file content, the connection.py can now import my class application in models. I run the file run.py which uses routes.py and it's him that calls operation.py

With some tests, I've find the lines who create my error:

```
from models import db
db.init_app(app)
import myapp.routes
```

But why????

Comment: It may be an issue related to the import path. Can you tell us how are you loading the `connection.py` file? Are you running it from the `updateto` directory?

Comment: No is running in my flask application. It's the routes.py file which calls connection.py when I launch run.py.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Flask specifically, but in Python you should generally include a `__init__.py` in **every** folder and subfolder for them to be recognised as modules and/or packages.

In the diagram you provide, there is no `__init__.py` in the `app` folder. Try putting one and re-post if that resolves your problem.

If it doesn't work, try:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

If the current working directory isn't the `app` directory, you'll have to work around this. One way would be:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/app')

import myapp.models
```

You can always see what directories are in your search path for modules by checking `sys.path`.

**Update:** Sorry I just realized that maybe you' re trying to run `connections.py` as a script. That would change you working directory to that of `connections.py`. Try importing `connections.py` from your main script with `import models` inside `connections.py` and see if you get an error.

**Update (in reply to Edit 4):** (I don't have enough reputation points to comment yet, so I reply here)

```
from models import db
db.init_app(app)
import myapp.routes
```

The problem in this piece of code is the `import myapp.routes`. Change that to `import routes` and it should work. As a rule of thumb, your *main script's directory* is your *root directory*. You can import **any** module located in your root directory from inside **any** other module (even modules inside a sub-folder!) with a simple `import module`.

Comment: I've try to put __init__.py empty in the root folder of app but same error. I've check the sys.path value from connection.py and I think the path is good: "C:\\app\\myapp". 
And I did not execute connection.py as a script but he was called inside my flask application. It's routes.py which call him.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Comment: I've already check this link. But if I try in connection.py "from ..libs import models" I've this error "ImportError: No module named libs"